# repeat reasult in arry loop

Tags: javascript, html

what is the problem in my code :

```
function Nums( use, dep, unt, prt, no){
      this.uses = use;
      this.department = dep;
      this.units = unt;
      this.part = prt;
      this.numbers = no;
    }

      var n1 = new Nums( "use1", "depart1", "unit1", "part1", "3562")
      var n2 = new Nums( "use2", "depart2", "unit2", "part2", "5226" )

      var obj = [n1, n2];
      var res = [];
      var r = "";
      var srch = "5"
      var div = document.getElementById("a");

      for( i = 0; i<obj.length; i++){
        for( key in obj[i]){
          if(obj[i][key].includes(srch)){
            res.push(obj[i])
            for( x = 0; x<res.length; x++){
              for( itm in res[x]){
                res2 = r += res[x][itm]
                div.innerHTML = res2;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(res)
```

i want to print the result in innerhtml but the output repeat 2 times in **" html"** and inside **console** , the result is Correct.
what is the Cause ?

innerHTML result :

> use1 => depart1 => unit1 => part1 => 3562 => *`use1 => depart1 => unit1 => part1 => 3562 =>`* use2 => depart2 => unit2 => part2 => 5226 =>

console result :

> [{uses :"use1", department:"depart1", units:"unit1", part:"part1", numbers:"3562" },
>   {uses :"use2", department:"depart2", units:"unit2", part:"part2", numbers:"5226"  }]

[See the code](https://codepen.io/ahmadmrf/pen/oQrjPQ/)

Comment: your codepen link is broken, could you please edit the post and include the output you are getting?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the current output and the expected output

Comment: because you loop over all the items in `res` each time and NOT just the one that was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop over the res array on every iteration and keep appending it.

```
  for( i = 0; i<obj.length; i++){
    for( key in obj[i]){
      if(obj[i][key].includes(srch)){
        res.push(obj[i])
        for( x = 0; x<res.length; x++){
          for( itm in res[x]){
            res2 = r += res[x][itm]
            div.innerHTML = res2;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It needs to be moved out or only loop over the last one you just added.

```
for (let i = 0; i<obj.length; i++) {
  for (let key in obj[i]){
    if(obj[i][key].includes(srch)) {
      res.push(obj[i])
    }
  }
}
for (let x = 0; x<res.length; x++) {  //pull out of the loops above
  for(let itm in res[x]) {
    res2 = r += res[x][itm]
  }
}
div.innerHTML = res2;  // only update DOM when done
```

And make sure you declare your variables, you are making a lot of globals.

Comment: can significantly reduce this code with a filter `obj.filter(x=>x.numbers.includes(srch))`

Comment: @COLBYBROOKS there is a lot that can be done, but that is not the question. filter() and map() would really simplify it.